# What is the difference between sagemaker-pytorch-training-toolkit and sagemaker-training-toolkit in SageMaker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pytorch, amazon-sagemaker

When porting PyTorch code / models to SageMaker, which one should we use:

**PyTorch Training Toolkit** (`https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-pytorch-training-toolkit/`) or
**SageMaker Training Toolkit** (`https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-training-toolkit`)? What's the difference when using these toolkits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SageMaker PyTorch Training Toolkit](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-pytorch-training-toolkit/) repository used to be the repository for the Sagemaker Pytorch Training Containers, and similarly the [SageMaker PyTorch Inference Toolkit](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-pytorch-inference-toolkit/) was the repository for the SageMaker PyTorch Inference containers.

At some point, AWS has started to directly use the DockerFiles of the Deep Learning containers from the [AWS Deep Learning Containers](https://github.com/aws/deep-learning-containers) repository so the repositories above were renamed because now AWS has used them to build a library that gets installed into the DL containers to make them SageMaker-compatible for training.

Example: From here https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-pytorch-training-toolkit/blob/master/setup.py Example of building a package that then gets installed in the DL container here: https://github.com/aws/deep-learning-containers/blob/1596489c9002cea08f8a2a7d2f4642c4b3727d52/pytorch/training/docker/1.6.0/py3/Dockerfile.cpu#L112

Answer (score 0):

The Pytorch Training Toolkit depends and extends the base [SageMaker Training Toolkit](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-training-toolkit%3E) with PyTorch specific support.